# Как добавить большой список слов в вектор?

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Нужно добавить большой список слов в вектор.

```
vector<string> words;
```

Таким способом получится не очень читабельно:

```
words.push_back("Word1");
words.push_back("Word2");
words.push_back("Word3");
```

и т.д.

Стоит поместить это в определенное место в коде или можно как-то подключить файлом?

Comment: Конкретный метод зависит от того, в каком виде у вас хранятся эти строки...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Вам могут помочь списки инициализации из 11 стандарта.

Если вы пользуетесь 11м стандартом, то можно это сделать так:

```
std::vector<std::string> words = {  "Word1"
                                  , "Word2"
                                  , "Word3"
                                  , "Word4"
                                  , "Word5"
                                  };
```

Но лучше поместить все ваши слова в файл (по слову на строке), и сделать функцию, которая прочитает файл и заполнит вектор словами из него

```
std::vector<std::string> GetWords(const std::string &file_name)
{
    std::ifstream fin(file_name);
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    while (std::getline(fin, line))
    {
        vec.push_back(line);
    }
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    //...
    std::vector<std::string> words = GetWords("words.txt");
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Файл со словами (words.txt):

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
Word4
Word5
```

Comment: Занятная расстановка запятых. :)

Comment: Этот способ делает ради систем контроля версий, тогда увеличение количества аргументов это просто плюс одна строка, а не плюс одна строка и изменение предыдущей строки (по крайней мере мне так объяснили этот способ, когда я его впервые увидел).

Comment: Пытаюсь подключить файлом, выходят ошибки: 1. fin (недопустимый неполный тип). 2.getline (Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "getline", соответствующие списку аргументов).

Comment: ага, уже заметил, поправил код: http://cpp.sh/57w4p (там просто изначально было `std::cin` :))

Comment: Так вот оно что. А я для этих целей использую `{`\n`"Word1",`\n`"Word2",`\n`"Word3",`\n`}`, ведь лишняя запятая в конце разрешена.

Comment: Не знал про запятую... Если так, то ваш вариант тоже хорош...